# Use JGit to access existing clone?

Tags: java, git, jgit

I have a clone of a repository on my computer already. I wish to create a Java program that pulls when it opens and pushes when it closes.

This is how I initiate JGit:

```
auth = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("[username]", "[pass]");

git = Git.open(new File(path_to_git + "\\.git"));

git.checkout().setName("master").call();

git.pull().setCredentialsProvider(auth).call();
```

This works the first time I start up, but if I close and reopen the program I get the error

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplicationWithArgs$2(LauncherImpl.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot check out from unborn branch
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CheckoutCommand.call(CheckoutCommand.java:235)
    at com.company.app.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:59)
    ... 11 more
```

When the program closes I call the function pushToGit() which is defined as:

```
public static void pushToGit() {

    try {

        git.remoteAdd()
            .setName("origin")
            .setUri(new URIish("https://github.com/[username]/[repo]"))
            .call();

        git.commit().setMessage("from database application").setAuthor(new PersonIdent("[name]","[email]")).call();

        git.push().setCredentialsProvider(auth).call();

    } catch (GitAPIException | URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Whenever I run the program, I need to delete the local repo and reclone it.

Comment: The exception is raised if JGit cannot find a `HEAD` ref. Does `Git.open` refer to an existing repository?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann yes, it works at first. But when I close the program (i.e. run the second code snippet in the question) it "ruins" the repo. As in after that I can't find the `HEAD` ref.

Comment: Did you try to disable the the calls in `pushToGit` step by step to find out which one 'ruins' your repository?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following example code snippet.

```
Git git = Git.cloneRepository()
  .setURI( "https://github.com/someRepoName" )
  .setDirectory( "/path/to/repo" )
  .setBranch( "refs/heads/master" )
  .call();
```

You can refer below the link for more details.
https://www.codeaffine.com/2015/11/30/jgit-clone-repository/

In the higher version of Jgit api, you can use `CloneCommand`, you can check below the link.

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand

Comment: I've tried this, but it does not work if the directory already contains the cloned repo. I get the error `Destination path "[repo]" already exists and is not an empty directory`

Comment: As a work around, you can delete the .git directory inside the folder to clone once agains. But if the folder contains .git directory, you cannot clone once again, you can do pull. This is the concept.

Comment: I understand, but i don't want to have to delete the `.git` folder everytime I run the program. Something within the `pushToGit` function is "ruining" the repo, because I after I run it I get the error in above.